# Singledispatch and type as an input argument

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-typing

I want to be able to do this:

```
from typing import Type
from functools import singledispatch

class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

@singledispatch
def foo(arg):
    print('default')

@foo.register
def _(arg: Type[A]):
    print(arg)

foo(A)
foo(B)
```

However, I get `Invalid annotation for 'arg'. typing.Type[__main__.arg] is not a class.`

I guess that `singledispatch` just does not support `typing` thoroughly for now. Is there any elegant workaround?

**UPD**
I can not modify `A` and `B`.

Comment: So you want `foo` to have different behavior when passed `A` or `B` as arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You can give `A` a metaclass, and then all subclasses of `A` will be instances of that metaclass:

```
from functools import singledispatch

class AMeta(type): pass

class A(metaclass=AMeta): pass

class B(A): pass

@singledispatch
def foo(arg):
    print('default')

@foo.register
def _(arg: AMeta):
    print('A or B')

foo(A) # A or B
foo(B) # A or B
foo(A()) # default

class C: pass

foo(C) # default
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about this. Updated my question, I do not have direct access to A and B. In this case, If I try to wrap them, it may be tricky to add desired metaclass due to mro, I guess. Should I accept the answer though?

Comment: @Tzoiker Not if it doesn't solve your problem.  Just to be clear, you want the function to have a different behavior if passed an object representing `A` or one of its subclasses?  `singledispatch` may not be able to do that, you may want to use `if issubclass(arg, A): return func1(arg) else return func2(arg)`

Comment: I ended up doing this. Was just curious if can it can be handled in another way.